# Vertical fluid layout

Tags: css, layout

Here's the layout I need to implement http://imm.io/16BQK

Inside of the wrapper element I have 3 rows. Top and bottom rows have their height as normal block elements - stretching with their content.

Middle block should take the rest of the space.

If I knew the height of top and bottom blocks I could use `display: table-row`. But I would like to have this automatic if only it's possible.

I'm fine with bits of JS but I'm not sure how to do it in elegant way taking into account I'd like to have this dynamic (middle block resizes when header/footer change their height).

Comment: `position:absolute` on the bottom block?

Comment: what if the content of middle block doesn't fit in to it? overflow?

Comment: @AxelAmthor yes. More precisely it will contain another .scroll wrapper that'll have 100% height and overflow: scroll. Think of emails list with header and footer full of controls

Comment: @Salman and what? How will it shrink the middle block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you can't do that with `display: table-row`, all you'd have to do is set `display: table` on the wrapper `div` and `display: table-row` on all the inner `div`'s. Then set the `div` in the middle to be `100%` high. This will ensure that both the top and bottom `div`'s are only as high as their content, the middle `div` will fill up the remaining space. It behaves exactly like an HTML `table`.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NyDQf/)</kbd>

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.header, .footer, .content {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: That obviously doesn't work. Height is not fixed, entire table expands to the effective height needed: http://jsfiddle.net/HHdJa/

Comment: @AxelAmthor - I kind of missed the point of OP wanting scrolling inside the middle row, as I didn't read all the comments on the question, but that is an easy fix: http://jsfiddle.net/HHdJa/1/.

Comment: @AxelAmthor - I'm sure OP could have done that, in fact OP mentions in the comments that it will be done, as for your point on the entire table expanding to the effective height needed, you shouldn't make the top and bottom div's take up more space than the whole height of the table, as doing so would not make sense. I think it is safe to assume that the height of the contents of the top and bottom div's combined won't exceed the height of the table. And in that case, the solution works just fine.

Comment: @AxelAmthor - And if the combined heights of the top and bottom div's do exceed the total height of the table, I'm sure OP wouldn't want anything else but for the height of the table to expand. Because if it didn't, the middle row would not be visible at all.

Comment: @AxelAmthor - Actually, if I give your solution the same treatment it looks very pretty: http://jsfiddle.net/tMNh2/7/.

Comment: @user1846192 as I directly mentioned I could do it if I new exact height of header and footer

Comment: Ok, so you don't know the exact height, but you don't need to using this solution, all you need to know is that the combined height of the header and the footer isn't taller than the containing table. See my last [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HHdJa/1/), the top and bottom `div`'s are only as high as their content, and the middle `div` is filling up the remaining space. The total height won't be any higher than the height set on the wrapper `div`, **unless** the combined height of the top and the bottom `div`'s is higher than the container, I don't think you can get a better solution.

Comment: hmm, I believe you, but in FF 21.0 that is _not working_ as described. In **chrome** it's working like a charm (your solution)!

Comment: @user1846192 stupid me, you're right

Comment: This really didn't work in FF but with minor additional trick I made it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Gcqzs/4/ (the trick is in moving stretching part to absolutely-positioned list and adding a wrapper inside of the table-row taking 100% height)

Answer (score -1):

needs some dhtml, since the inner box won't shrink/expand automatically:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; top:0; width:300px;
border:1px  solid black; left:0; height:550px;">
    <div id="topdiv" style=" 
    border:1px  solid red;">lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div id="main" style="border:1px  solid green;">
        <div id="content" style="overflow:scroll;">lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ... lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomdiv" style="position:absolute; 
    border:1px  solid blue; left:0px; bottom:0px;display:block;width:100%;">lorem ipsum dolor site...<br>lorem ipsum dolor site...
        </div>
</div>
```

and

```
function setSizes()
{
    var topHeight = $("#topdiv").height();
    var bottomHeight = $("#bottomdiv").height();
    var mainHeight = $("#wrapper").height() - topHeight - bottomHeight;
    //alert(mainHeight);
    $("#content").height(mainHeight - 5);
}

setSizes();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tMNh2/2/

heights/corrections depend on borders etc. and are just as an example and probably needs some enhancement.

Comment: > I'm fine with bits of JS but I'm not sure how to do it in elegant way taking into account I'd like to have this dynamic (middle block resizes when header/footer change their height).

Comment: whenever the top or bottom contents are changing you may call setsizes().

Comment: Thanks for the downvoter not having a better idea. Problem is that the actual heights are unknown and even the remaining height may get negative. This can IMHO not be done by css-fiddling alone.

Comment: I'd like some automatic solution, not calling setsizes manually each time. Otherwise your proposal is obvious :)